# Monaco Editor - Creating custom intellisense

Tags: intellisense, monaco-editor

I was wondering if it is possible to merge the default suggestion list with custom suggestions created in registerCompletionItemProvider.
I tried to do it but the customs I create always overwrite the default suggestions of the editor, resulting in having only the suggestions which I have manually coded.
One solution for this would probably be to create the algorithm that gets suggestions from scratch, but that would still overwrite the default keywords and such.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** 
I kinda worked around it by adding the following to my registerCompletionItemProvider function. I still cannot get the default suggestions for e.g. Javascript to include in my custom language.

```
let variables = model.getValueInRange({startLineNumber: 1, startColumn: 1, 
                                                endLineNumber: 10000000, 
                                                endColumn: 10000000}).match(/[^\W\d](\w|[-']{1,2}(?=\w))*/g) || [];

            _.each(variables, function (val,key){
                if (!(suggestions.some(function (el) {
                    return el.label === val;
                }))){
                    suggestions.push({
                        label: val,
                        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Variable,
                        insertText: val
                    })
                }
            })
            return {suggestions: suggestions};
```